# How to Manually Start Visual Studio Conversion Wizard

Tags: visual-studio-2010, conversion-wizard

I want to convert my .NET Website that is currently in .NET Framework version 3.5 SP 1 to 4.0. Now you get a conversion wizard when you open a VS 2008 solution in VS 2010. The wizard will convert the solution to 2010 and at the same time can convert the projects to .NET 4.0. I already converted my solution to VS 2010 but did not at the time convert to .NET 4.0. Does anyone know how to start the VS Conversion Wizard manually? According to this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx) it should start when you open the solution, that is not the case for me.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The wizard converts solutions and projects from previous VS versions to the current one. It will not open again, because you already converted it to VS2010.

To change to .NET 4.0:

1. Right-click on the project in your Solution Explorer, and click "Properties".
2. Switch to the "Compile" tab.
3. Click the "Advanced Compile Options..." button.
4. Change the Target Framework to ".NET Framework 4."

Comment: There are no tabs at all in the "Solution 'Website1' Property Pages" window.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You right clicked on the solution, instead of the project. On the Solution Explorer, right click one level below the solution, where it says "Website1" and then click properties. Also, if you use VS2017, the "Compile" tab no longer exists, and the "Target Framework" option appears on the "Application" tab

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, The wizard doesn't do anything that switching target type in the project won't do. You might not get the option to back up, but you're already doing versioning, right?

Comment: Yes, I wan't sure that switching the target framework was the same thing the wizard was doing with regard to the framework version. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I could determine, the wizard does a number of things: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To amend the Framework target, i went to the property pages of the site > build tab > updated the target framework. It re-built the web site successfully for me.