# How can I access "Visual Studio Conversion Wizard" for a WebSite?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-4.0, conversion-wizard

I'm using [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx) to convert my ASP.NET 2.0 web application to an ASP.NET 4.0 application.

However, the article states that I will be prompted to change to .NET 4.0 when I open up my project/website.

As I've previously declined this dialog I'm not longer being prompted.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097191/how-to-manually-start-visual-studio-conversion-wizard) which states I should click on the Properties tab of my solution, but I only have "Properties Window". Perhaps this is just for Projects/

How can I get the conversion wizard to reappear for my WebSite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to get the Conversion Wizard to reappear, but I have been able to convert to .NET 4.0 by:

- Right Clicking on my website
- Selecting `Property Pages`
- Then go to `Build` tab
- Change `Target Framework`

This made all the changes to my web.config automatically just like the conversion wizard would.

Comment: In VS 2010, there's no Build tab. Click the Compile tab, then "Advanced Compile Options", and _then_ "Target Framework".