# Visual studio 2010 convert project manually

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project-conversion

I've got an asp.net project. When I first opened it up with VS 2010 I got the project conversion wizard and ignored it. But now I want to convert my project to latest version.

Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097191/how-to-manually-start-visual-studio-conversion-wizard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not popping up when you open the project in VS 2010, then you've already converted it.

To change the framework to 4.0, right click on the project and select Properties. On the application tab of the project properties, change the Target Framework to .Net Framework 4.

This will update web.configs and such files the same way the conversion wizard does anwyays.